# Connectionstring error after encrypted using aspnet_regiis.exe

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, rsa, aspnet-regiis.exe

I've encrypted the connectionstring in my web.config file using the steps in the link below:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/WebFarmConnStringsNet20.aspx

However, whenever I call my application, it will give the following error:

> Failed to decrypt using provider
>   'CustomProvider'. Error message from
>   the provider: The RSA key container
>   could not be opened.

The server where I perform the encryption is a 64-bit Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2. Because of that I assign the ACL to `NT Authority\Network Service`. Yet it still doesn't work.

Hope someone has some ideas what else do I need to check to get this working.

PS. If I used the default rsa key `NetFrameworkConfigurationKey` for encryption, then the connection string will not have an access problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the source of the problem, and boy was it embarrassing. In the attribute keyContainerName, I spelled the name incorrectly.

That it. That's what caused the problem.

Apparently, the encryption will work even if you provide an incorrect keyContainerName, which I incorrectly assumed will fail. So, once I decrypt the connectionstring and re-encrypt with the right keyContainerName, it works fine.

BTW, make sure to decrypt your existing connectionstring before correcting the keyContainerName. The aspnet_regiis.exe will complain about bad data, because the provider is now different.

Comment: mark this as answer so it'll disappear from the unanswered stuff

Comment: Done. I didn't realized until today that SO now allows the question owner to set his own answer.

Comment: Maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124389/failed-to-decrypt-using-provider-rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add the

```
<configProtectedData>
```

to your web.config?