# How to encrypt IP, username and password in webconfig file?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using entity framework in my project and its created connection string in `web.config`, I want to encrypt `ip`, `username` and `password` because it can be easily accessible. how can i encrypt these `credential` ?

Comment: If your web.config is easily accessible, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: it's not about hackers only ...if someone copy my code then he can easily delete my database or tables by seeing credentials from web.config ..so is there any way to encrypt this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`aspnet_regiis` command line tool to achieve this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config).

However, I would advise that you seek to do this [as part of your build process somehow](http://blog.mikaellundin.name/2010/05/19/encrypt-your-web-config-with-msbuild.html). This way you retain the unencrypted values in your source control, but the encrypted values in deployed environments.

Comment: Thanks @Reddog for the reply.,,i downloaded  the zip file of code which given in the link and try to run it...it is giving error "Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened."  after this i took help form this link " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124389/failed-to-decrypt-using-provider-rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider " ..But unfortunately its not working and still i am getting same error .