# RSA encryption with same key in different server not working

Tags: .net, encryption, rsa, connection-string

We are encrypting connection string in config file using RSA.

Server 1:
We created RSA container and RSAKeys.xml created and encrypted connection string.

While decrypting it works fine in same server.

Server 2:

We created RSA container in same name of server 1. and created RSAKeys.xml created and replaced with RSAkeys.xml from Server 1.

While we try to decrypt the connection string which has been encrypted in Server 1 is not working.

Facing below issue

```
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The parameter is incorrect
```

We can't able to maintain 2 different encrypted keys in source level. Can someone please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2w117ede(v=vs.140)

Comment: Please always provide details for the runtime environment and also put in the right tags for those. Is this a programming related question?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16124389/589259) answer your question?